# Spatial adjustment of shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-plugins, vector-layer, spatial-adjustment

I am trying to spatially adjust a shapefile containing several polygons, which slightly shift from its raster image. I want to change these features on accurate location so I am using the Vector Bender plugin in QGIS but it does not work correctly. When I run this tool, my shapefile starts landing somewhere far away from its current location.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the data?

Comment: Please provide screenshots showing with what you start, what exactly you do, what your workflow produces.

Comment: Did you consider affine transformation? https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#affine-transform

Comment: It is also possible to use the georeferencer now since QGIS 3.26 https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog326/index.html#feature-georeferencing-vector-layers-in-georeferencer.

Comment: @Babel, the Affine Transformation plugin is for older versions of QGIS, and I use the latest version of QGIS, which is why I use vector bender.

Comment: Now, the vector bender plugin worked fine when I set the projection of the vector bender layer. But In comparison with ArcMap, I need to add many points for the spatial adjustment.

Comment: No need to use a plugin for Affine transformation - `Menu Processing > Toolbox > Affine transform` or use QGIS expressions with `affine_transform()`

Comment: You probably need to improve the accuracy of your projection by adding a grid transform